# browserify doing nothing from command line

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, browserify

I'm totally new to node.js, so I'm guessing this is a dumb question..

I have an ubuntu machine, on which I have installed browserify with npm:

```
sudo npm install browserify -g
```

I can require this module if I open a node.js shell, but when I try to run it from the command line nothing happens:

```
ubuntu:~$ browserify
ubuntu:~$ browserify f -o f3
ubuntu:~$
```

whats going on here? The command is found but does nothing and prints nothing??

Thanks

Comment: have you gone through the doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify?

Comment: @elaijuh - yes I have... for now I'm getting around this issue with explicitly calling `nodejs browserify infile -o outfile`. Not sure why this does not work as advertised on a fresh ubuntu 12.04 machine on aws though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably with 'node' vs 'nodejs' environment.
Type `which browserify` in your terminal and then edit the file with your preferred text editor: `emacs /usr/local/bin/browserify`.

The very first line of the file might read something like `#!/usr/bin/env node`. Just change it to call `nodejs` instead of `node` so that it reads `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs`

This has to be the the easiest way. And it works with many other tools that depend on node (like coffeescript relp/compiler, mocha testing tool and pretty much anything else that depends on `node`)

Answer (score 0):

do you have `f` in current path and have you checked if `f3` is generated?
i see usually output to stdout and redirect to bundle by `>`, like below:

```
browserify f.js > f3.js
```